# Javascript in foreach php - Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I am trying to put javascript into a foreach statement in php. The problem is i only get one element. (because php is server side and javascript is client side).

This is my code :

```
 <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $item): ?>



<tr>
    <td class="name">

       <?php echo  
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('attributes.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

        <?php echo $item->getName(); echo '<br>';?> 


        <div class="toggle-inhalt">Beschreibung</div>


         <div class="beschreibung-checkout slide-up"><?php
              $_product = $item->getProduct();
              $pid = $_product->getId();
              $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
              /* getting some attributes */

              echo $beschreibung = $product->getData('beschreibung'); 
              ?>
             </div>


                    <script>

                    (function(document) {
                        "use strict";

                        var hidden_el  = document.getElementsByClassName("beschreibung-
checkout"),
                            control_el = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-inhalt");

                        if (hidden_el.length < 1 || control_el.length < 1) {
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get the elements
                        hidden_el  = hidden_el[0];
                        control_el = control_el[0];

                        control_el.onclick = function() {
                            var element_classes = (" "+hidden_el.className+" ").replace(/[\n
\t\r]/g, " "),
                                remove_class    = "slide-down",
                                add_class       = "slide-up",
                                is_showing      = element_classes.indexOf(" "+remove_class+" ") 
> -1;

                            if ( ! is_showing) {
                                // Switch variable values
                                remove_class = [add_class, add_class = remove_class][0];
                            }

                            // Remove the previous class (if present) and add the new class
                            hidden_el.className = (element_classes.replace(" "+remove_class+" ",
"") + " "+add_class+" ").trim();

                            return false;
                        };
                    })(document);
                  </script>
.........
```

it s just a simple slide up and down on a div element. 
The **problem** is : i want to get for every product its name and its own description.

As an Example : this picture : http://bengar.de/media/magentocheckout.png. The description of the first pruduct(L-240) is showing without any problem. but not for the second product(Haltegriff)!

So i think i need ajax for this or an array. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Have you tried using CMS Block and calling that block under your above php code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not repeating your JavaScript at all.

just add a class to all elements and maybe also a custom attribute to each div then use the jQuery each function.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Thank you for helping me! How can i assign a class to all elements ?? i only have one element. So i need i have to make an Array ? but which elements have to be saved in that array ?.. (I don't have any known ids - moreover the ids are arbitrary!)